# android get list of files from package

Tags: android, android-resources

How can I get all list of `.json` config files, which are located NOT on SD card, but in my package?  Bellow on the image showed the files in the folder which I want to access. The idea is the following: when application starts I want to get list of config files, the path to them and display that to testers to choose to what server connect to. How can I do that? I was looking for `PackageManager` and `AssetManager`, but resultless.

When I put folder configs to folder assets, this code game me a list of available configs, but how can I get full path to them to read them?

```
AssetManager am = getAssets();
String s = getPackageName();
Resources tmp = pm.getResourcesForApplication(s);
String [] arr = am.list("configs2");
```

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved my problem. This is the structure of my project:
[image]

1. To get list of files from application package, you need to put all your files you want to get into assets folder. Here is the code:

   private ArrayList getPackageConfigList()
               {
                   AssetManager am = getAssets();
                   String [] arr = null;
                   try
                   {
                       arr = am.list(folder);
                   }
                   catch(IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

   ```
               ArrayList<String> flist = new ArrayList<String>();

               for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
               {
                   flist.add(PKG + arr[i]);
                   Log.d(tag, PKG+ arr[i]);
               }

               return flist;
           }
   ```

   2. To read concrete file from package:

   private String loadConfigFromPackage(String fileName)
       {
           AssetManager am = getAssets();
           InputStream in = null;
           String result = null;

   ```
   try
   {
       //open file, read to buffer, convert to string
       in = am.open(folder + "/" + fileName);
       int size = in.available();
       byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
       in.read(buffer);
       in.close();
       result = new String(buffer);
   }
   catch(IOException e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   finally
   {
       try
       {
           in.close();
       }
       catch(Exception ex){}
   }
   return result;
   ```

   }

Comment: Glad you solved your problem! Although it's not recommended to read it in as a byte buffer, but use a BufferedReader as it's safer:
`BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input_stream))` then use `reader.readLine()`

Answer (score 1):

To do a similar thing I've used the following command:

`InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.raw_data_file);`

Where the file `raw_data_file` was in the path `res/raw/raw_data_file.txt`. You can then read the file using the InputStream as normal. I'm sure you'd be able to do a similar thing with your file where it is, but as a rule I'd normally put any resources in the `res(ources)` folder

Comment: Thanks. Can I somehow get files from "configs" folder in it's current location?

Comment: Try `am.open(configs/fileName)`, which again returns an InputStream